# Laravel background-image Valor de propiedad no valido

Tags: laravel, background

estoy agregando una imagen a una tag div, el nombre de la imagen la tomo de la base de datos, aqui el codigo:

```
<div class="single_details details_bg_1" style="background-image: {{ url('storage/edificios/'.$edificio->slider_imagen1) }}"></div>
```

las imagenes estan almacenadas en `public/storage/edificios/` a traves del inspeccionador me esta indicando que el valor de la propiedad no es valido, y se#ana al background-image,     `background-image: http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/edificios/slider_imagen1-1650650190.png;`

copie y pegue esa url y desde el explorador me muestra la imagen, por que que descarto que sea la ruta, que estoy haciendo mal???
estoy usando laravel 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la solucion:

```
 style="background-image: url({{url('storage/edificios/'.$edificio->slider_imagen1)}}) ;"
```

sucede que para css  la propiedad background-image  se asigna el valor de la siguiente forma:

```
background-image: url('valor');
```

entonces como la ruta proviene de una ruta laravel, le agregamos la plantilla blade url() para que interprete la ruta y variable que proviene de la base de datos, por lo tanto a solucion quedaria:

```
<div class="single_details details_bg_1"  style="background-image: url({{url('storage/edificios/'.$edificio->slider_imagen1)}}) ;" ></div>
```

Comment: Recuerda que estás en SO en español, por favor traduce tu pregunta para que no sea cerrada. También sería recomendable que agregaras una explicación del por qué esa es la solución para que otros usuarios con el mismo problema puedan encontrar la respuesta.

Comment: perdoname bro, eso sucede cuando se hablan mas de 2 idiomas. gracias!

Comment: No olvides aceptar la respuesta, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución fácilmente y ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas